# systemd-journald[290]: Failed to rewrite entry(22 items, 735 bytes); ignoring: Read-only file system

Tags: boot, virtualbox, login, read-only, systemd-logind

I am on dual boot Ubuntu 20.04. After I login (enter password and press enter key), a blank screen flashes followed by the non-stop chain of the following message scrolling.
message:

systemd-journald[290]: Failed to rewrite entry(22 items, 735 bytes); ignoring: Read-only file system

systemd-journald[290]: Failed to rewrite entry(22 items, 746 bytes); ignoring: Read-only file system

I have attached the screenshot for reference.

The story of what I did before the error popped up,  goes like this:

1. I installed the Oracle Virtual box, and added an application(SAS) to run on it.

To do that(install SAS), the following steps were performed:
A. downloaded and installed virtualization software Oracle VirtualBox for Linux.
B. Created a folder named 'SASUniversityEdition' (no spaces) on /home, and another subfolder named 'myfolders' inside the folder  'SASUniversityEdition'.
C. Downloaded the SAS University Edition vApp.
D. Launched VirtualBox and select File > Import Appliance.
In the Import Virtual Appliance window, clicked the folder icon to the right of the field.
In the file browser window, selected the SAS University Edition .ova file, and clicked Open.
Clicked Next. Then clicked Import in the Appliance Settings window.
Shared the "myfolders" folder with VirtualBox.
E.
In VirtualBox, selected the SAS University Edition vApp, and then selected Machine > Settings.
In the navigation pane, selected Shared Folders, and then clicked the Add Folder icon (+) in the upper right of the Settings window.
In the Add Share window, selected Other as the folder path.
In the file browser window, opened the SASUniversityEdition folder, and selected the myfolders subfolder i created in step 1. Clicked Select Folder. Then clicked OK.

In the Add Share window, confirmed that **Read-only is selected**(actual instruction is: Confirm Read-only **not** selected).
Selected the Auto-mount option, and clicked OK.
Clicked OK again to close the Settings window.

F. In VirtualBox, selected the SAS University Edition vApp in the left column, and then ctlick Start.
In a web browser on my computer, entered http://localhost:10080 to open the SAS University Edition: Information Center
From the SAS University Edition: Information Center, clicked Start SAS Studio.

Here's the link to the webpage where you can see those instructions I followed:
https://www.sas.com/en_in/software/university-edition/download-software.html#linux

2. I used the SAS for some time but then the system started hanging, and as usual I force shutdown the system (long press-hold power button).
3. On switching on system, as usual, the selection screen appeared (windows or Ubuntu), it is dual boot system.
4. After selecting Ubuntu, the screen showed some error. I don't recall it entirely, but some of the error is this:

/dev/sda5: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found

acpi error thread cannot release mutex

fsck error on boot: /dev/sda5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

5. Then I performed the following operation:

fsck /dev/sda5
And entered Yes (y) to for each error.
entered exit
rebooted system

6. Now it will take me to the login page after I select Ubuntu at boot option.
   But after I login, the following error keeps scrolling:

systemd-journald[290]: Failed to rewrite entry(22 items, 735 bytes); ignoring: Read-only file system

systemd-journald[290]: Failed to rewrite entry(22 items, 746 bytes); ignoring: Read-only file system

[image: screenshot of the screen after I login]

Comment: are you using btrfs in your root partition?

Comment: @christianbueno.1 I solved the issue by reinstalling ubuntu